# how force download aar version of dependencies in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-management, androidx, android-glide

Recently I upgraded `glide` from `4.8.0` to `4.9.0`.

As you can see added some extra dependencies in that latest version:
https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.bumptech.glide/glide/4.9.0/aar

It added `vectordrawable-animated 27.1.1`

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>animated-vector-drawable</artifactId>
      <version>27.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I used androidX too in my project and when I want to sync gradle, Occurred this error:

```
':app': Unable to build Kotlin project configuration
Details: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: 
Could not find vectordrawable-animated.jar (androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://maven.google.com/androidx/vectordrawable/vectordrawable-animated/1.0.0/vectordrawable-animated-1.0.0.jar
```

As you can see it uses this link for downloading this dependency:

https://maven.google.com/androidx/vectordrawable/vectordrawable-animated/1.0.0/vectordrawable-animated-1.0.0.jar

**but it NOT FOUND!**

but if you change `.jar` to `.aar` it's ready to download.

https://maven.google.com/androidx/vectordrawable/vectordrawable-animated/1.0.0/vectordrawable-animated-1.0.0.aar

How force to use `aar` version  without upgrading something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to download only the aar artifact ignoring the transitive dependencies use the **`@aar`** notation.

```
implementation "androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0@aar"
```